# frequency plot using ggplot hangs or not showing plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with 880,000 rows and 2 columns ('width', 'group') in the following form: 
width group

```
20    a 
25    a 
20    a 
25    a 
35    b 
40    c 
20    d 
25    d
```

I want to create a frequency polygon for all the four groups in the same figure but so far I remained unsuccessful.

```
df1 = cbind(ceiling(rnorm(20, 30,5)), 'a')   
df2 = cbind(ceiling(rnorm(40, 80,10)), 'b')   
df3 = cbind(ceiling(rnorm(30, 50,8)), 'c')   
df4 = cbind(ceiling(rnorm(35, 30,7)), 'd')   
dfrm = rbind(df1,rbind(df2,rbind(df3,df4)))  
colnames(dfrm)=c('width', 'group')           
dfrm = as.data.frame(dfrm)
```

`qplot(width, data = dfrm, geom="freqpoly", binwidth = 100)` #not showing any plot

```
ggplot(dfrm, aes(width, ..density.., colour = group)) +                  
   geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 1000)  #create more than four plots
```

I need to draw something similar to the  following:

http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/graphics/996ae62d750dfccac8805fa0c87168cc.png

Or

http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/graphics/55078149a733dd1a0b42a57faf847036.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems.  First, the way you have created `dfrm`, `width` is a factor.

```
> str(dfrm)
'data.frame':   125 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ width: Factor w/ 60 levels "106","20","21",..: 7 7 17 10 9 9 6 7 17 4 ...
 $ group: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

This is because `cbind` creates a matrix which must have all the same type and since there is a character, it is a character matrix.  Later transformation to a data.frame makes them into factors.  This can be fixed with

```
dfrm$width <- as.numeric(as.character(dfrm$width))
```

or better, not making matrices to begin with

```
df1 = data.frame(width=ceiling(rnorm(20, 30,5)), group='a')   
df2 = data.frame(width=ceiling(rnorm(40, 80,10)), group='b')   
df3 = data.frame(width=ceiling(rnorm(30, 50,8)), group='c')   
df4 = data.frame(width=ceiling(rnorm(35, 30,7)), group='d')   
dfrm = rbind(df1,df2,df3,df4)
```

This is enough to make a graph

```
ggplot(dfrm, aes(width, ..density.., colour = group)) +                  
   geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 1000)
```

[image]

Though it looks like there is only one line, there are actually 4, all on top of each other. You only see the last one drawn (group "d").  This points out the second problem: your `binwidth` is way too large for this data.

```
ggplot(dfrm, aes(width, ..density.., colour = group)) +                  
   geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 10)
```

`geom_freqpoly` does not appear to have a `fill` aesthetic, though.

[image]